# Is $ord(xy)$ independent of $ord(x)$ and $ord(y)$ in a finite group?

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $r,s,t>1$ be positive integers. Must there exist a finite group $G$ with elements $x$ and $y$ such that $ord(x)=r$, $ord(y)=s$, and $ord(xy)=t$?

The answer is probably "yes." Is there a nice description of such a $G$?

Comment: I voted to close, but on reflection I think it was largely because of the imperative structure of the question (this immediately sets of the homework flag in most of our minds). The universal example is not finite unless $r=s=2$, and after a few minutes thought it's not obvious to me how to build $G$. This is a precise and nonobvious mathematical question, so I'm going to edit it and encourage others to vote to reopen it. I don't really care if this is homework.

Comment: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1145/is-ordxy-independent-of-ordx-and-ordy-in-a-finite-group/

Comment: At any rate, the way to build $G$ is as follows.  Take the $r,s,t$--triangle group $T = \langle x, y \ | \ x^r = y^s = (xy)^t \rangle$, in which $x$, $y$, and $xy$ have the correct orders, but which, as Anton mentions, is usually infinite.  $T$ is, however, residually finite (since it is linear).  Now just pick some finite quotient $G$ of $T$ in which all of the nontrivial powers of $x$, $y$, and $xy$ survive.

Comment: @Richard: I see that it's enough to show $T$ is residually finite, but I don't see why $T$ is linear (this means subgroup of $GL_n$, right?) or why linear implies residually finite.

Comment: See here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24913/quick-proofs-of-hard-theorems/24940#24940

Comment: @Anton: Finitely generated linear groups are always residually finite: this is a result of Malcev; I sketched (one of many possible) proof here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9628/finitely-presented-sub-groups-of-gln-c/14244#14244


Comment: @Anton: $T$ is either finite or a discrete group of orientation preserving isometries of the Euclidean or hyperbolic plane.  These isometry groups are $\mathbb{R}^2 \ltimes \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathrm{SO}_0(2,1)$, where $\mathrm{SO}_0(2,1)$ is the identity component of $\mathrm{SO}_0(2,1)$. 

Comment: Darn, that should read $\mathbb{R}^2 \rtimes \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. 

Comment: Even in the finite case it is a subgroup of $SO(3)$, no?

Comment: Yeah, but finite groups are obviously residually finite. :)

Comment: Now, what's the etiquette on who posts the answer?

Comment: Richard - as you posted the correct answer in a comment, it seems only fitting that you should post the answer.  No?

Comment: There can be more than one answer; indeed, general SE philosophy is there should be more than one answer.

Comment: I agree with HW: Richard should post the answer!


Comment: I wonder if there is a way to formulate this problem so that x and y are random elements, chosen randomly from a random group, and then ask whether order(xy) is independent of order(x) and of order(y) as random variables...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be elements of a group $G$. If $a$ has order $m$ and $b$ has
order $n$, what can we say about the order of $ab$? The next theorem shows
that we can say nothing at all.

THEOREM: For any integers $m,n,r>1$, there exists a finite group $G$ with
elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ has order $m$, $b$ has order $n$, and $ab$
has order $r$.

PROOF: We shall show that, for a suitable prime power $q$, there exist elements $a$
and $b$ of $SL_{2}(F_{q})$ such that $a$, $b$, and $ab$ have
orders $2m$, $2n$, and $2r$ respectively. As $-I$ is the unique element of
order $2$ in $SL_{2}(F_{q})$, the images of $a$, $b$, $ab$ in
$SL_{2}(F_{q})/\{\pm I\}$ will then have orders $m$, $n$, and $r$
as required.

Let $p$ be a prime number not dividing $2mnr$. Then $p$ is a unit in the
finite ring $\mathbb{Z}/2mnr\mathbb{Z}$, and so some power of it, $q$ say,
is $1$ in the ring. This means that $2mnr$ divides $q-1$. As the group
$F_{q}^{\times}$ has order $q-1$ and is cyclic,
there exist elements $u$, $v$, and $w$ of $F_{q}^{\times}$ having
orders $2m$, $2n$, and $2r$ respectively.

Let
$$
a=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
u & 1\\
0 & u^{-1}
\end{array}
\right)$$

and $$b=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}%
v & 0\\
t & v^{-1}%
\end{array}
\right)$$
(elements of $SL_{2}(F_{q})$), where $t$ has been chosen so that
$$
uv+t+u^{-1}v^{-1}=w+w^{-1}.
$$

The characteristic polynomial of $a$ is $(X-u)(X-u^{-1})$, and so $a$ is
similar to $diag(u,u^{-1})$. Therefore $a$ has order $2m$. Similarly $b$ has
order $2n$. The matrix
$$
ab=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
uv+t & v^{-1}\\
u^{-1}t & u^{-1}v^{-1}%
\end{array}
\right)  ,
$$
has characteristic polynomial
$$
X^{2}-(uv+t+u^{-1}v^{-1})X+1=(X-w)(X-w^{-1})\text{,}
$$
and so $ab$ is similar to $diag(w,w^{-1})$. Therefore $ab$ has order
$2r$.

I don't know who found this beautiful proof. Apparently the
original proof of G.A. Miller is very complicated; see [MO24940](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24913/quick-proofs-of-hard-theorems/24940#24940).

Comment: I give up --- I'll someone else fix the TeX.

Comment: ok, done. I hope I didn't mess anything else up.

Comment: Thanks Anton -- beautiful! (Maybe I should read the instructions.)

Comment: Nice! I don't know who first gave this proof either, but I first read it from a post by Derek Holt: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/24913/quick-proofs-of-hard-theorems/24940#24940

Answer (score 15):

Here's my comment as an answer:

Take the $r,s,t$--(ordinary) triangle group $T(r,s,t)=\langle x,y \ | \ x^r=y^s=(xy)^t = 1 \rangle$, in which $x$, $y$, and $xy$ have the correct orders. See the section on ``von Dyck" groups [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group).

As Anton mentions in his comment, $T(r,s,t)$ is infinite when $\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t} \leq 1$. However, $T(r,s,t)$ is residually finite.  The easiest way to see this is to use the facts that finitely generated linear groups are residually finite (due to Malcev, as Steve D mentions), and the fact that $T(r,s,t)$ is linear.

To see that $T(r,s,t)$ is linear, note that when $\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t} = 1$, it is a discrete subgroup of the affine group $\mathbb{R}^2 \rtimes \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, and when $\frac{1}{r} + \frac{1}{s} + \frac{1}{t} < 1$, it is a discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{Isom}^+(\mathbb{H}^2) \cong \mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathrm{SO}_0(2,1)$, where $\mathrm{SO}_0(2,1)$ is the identity component of $\mathrm{SO}(2,1)$.  See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group) again.

Now, since $T(r,s,t)$ is residually finite, there is a quotient $G$ in which $$x, x^2, \ldots, x^{r-1}, y, y^2, \ldots, y^{s-1}, (xy), (xy)^2, \ldots, (xy)^{t-1}$$ are all nontrivial. This is the $G$ you seek.

Also see Steve D's answer [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24913/quick-proofs-of-hard-theorems/24940#24940).