# injectivity radius of hyperbolic surface

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, systolic-geometry

Given a positive real number $l$. Does there exist a closed hyperbolic surface $X$ so that injectivity radius not less than $l$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Buser in 1992 gives a lower bound on the Bers constant for surfaces of genus $g$, and it goes to infinity as $g$ goes to infinity.  So this means there's compact hyperbolic surfaces whose injectivity radius is arbitrarily large, but you have to go to high genus to realize them.

P. Buser. *Geometry and spectra of compact Riemann surfaces* Prog. Math. Vol 106. (1992)

The genus needs to grow like the square of the injectivity radius.  Probably a good way to find this surface would be to use Fenchel-Nielsen coordinates, where the pants correspond to points on a planar square lattice and you want to connect the vertices in some (likely non-planar) tri-valent graph configuration, so that it represents pants. Then you want to connect the edges in a way so that there's no short closed loops in the resulting graph.  So I'm describing a surface that's less the gluing-together of pants, but more the gluing together of quadratically-many "short shorts".

Comment: @Ryan:  Actually, don't we have $g\geq \cosh^2(l/2)$ by Gauss-Bonnet?  This is a much faster growth of $g$ in terms of $l$ than you indicate.

Comment: @Robert: I should have thought of that.  I'm teaching Gauss-Bonnet in my differential geometry class this week.  


Answer (score 8):

Let $Y$ be a compact hyperbolic surface.  There are only finitely many closed geodesics in $Y$ whose lengths are less that $\ell$.  Since $\pi_1(Y)$ is residually finite, there is a normal subgroup of finite index in $\pi_1(Y)$ that does not contain anything in the conjugacy classes corresponding to these geodesics. The corresponding finite covering space $X$ of $Y$ has no closed geodesics of length less than $\ell$.

Comment: Ditto for all compact hyperbolic manifolds. 

Comment: Yes, I should've said that.  Thanks, Misha.

Comment: Richard, maybe you should also mention that you use normal finite index subgroups, this will take care of the base point business. 

Comment: I didn't find the word "congruence subgroup" on this page, so I thought I would comment that using congruence subgroups may be more elementary than appealing to residual finiteness of 3-manifolds.

Comment: One (usually) proves residual finiteness of hyperbolic 3-manifolds using congruence quotients, so this is just the same thing.

Comment: Exactly my point.  Congruence subgroups provide both lower bounds for systole and proof of RF for arithmetic manifolds.  I don't remember if RF is also true for nonarithmetic ones, but I assume it is harder.

Comment: I see that the paper 

Thurston, William P. Three-dimensional manifolds, Kleinian groups and hyperbolic geometry. Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.) 6 (1982), no. 3, 357–381

proves RF in the Haken case.

Comment: Hempel, John Residual finiteness for 3 -manifolds. Combinatorial group theory and topology (Alta, Utah, 1984), 379–396, Ann. of Math. Stud., 111, Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton, NJ, 1987 proved this again in the Haken case.  I guess he wasn't convinced by Thurston.  Does anybody know the history of this?

Comment: In response to your first comment, no, it's not significantly harder.  In any Jacobson ring you have enough maximal ideals to prove residual finiteness.  Malcev observed this in the 40s; the upshot is that any fg linear group is residually finite.

Comment: Re: your later comments, no, I don't think that Hempel didn't believe Thurston; rather, Thurston characteristically doesn't give all the details.  Hempel's paper shows how to deduce residual finiteness from geometrization.

Comment: Do you have a reference where your remarks on Jacobson rings and linear groups are treated in more detail?

Comment: The proof was written up by Steve D in this MO answer: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/9628/finitely-presented-sub-groups-of-gln-c/14244#14244 .  Roger Alperin wrote up an elementary proof in his paper 'An elementary account of Selberg's lemma'.